# Facebook Deleting Requests

Tags: java, facebook, request

I am trying to removing facebook requests by using graph api :

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>]?access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]
```

Like this:

```
DeleteMethod method = new DeleteMethod("https://graph.facebook.com/requestId_userId?access_token=token");
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.executeMethod(method);
```

Server sends me status code 400 but when I open this link on browser FB returns me information about request. What I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get an error message with that 400 ?

Comment: just only 400 - Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem using attribute "method" in http request and replacing user access token on app access token like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[requestId_userId]?access_token=[appToken]&method=delete
```

this url works on all requests types: post, get and delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C# facebook SDK you can use this:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(Config.FacebookAppId, Config.FacebookAppSecret);
var result = fb.Delete(string.Format("{0}_{1}?access_token={2}", facebookRequestId, facebookUserId, fb.AccessToken));
```